# Install Qt5 on Virtualbox, get segmentation fault

Tags: virtualbox, qt5

I have virtualbox(5.2.2) created from ubuntu-16.04.3-desktop-amd64.iso, on Windows host. I downloaded qt-opensource-linux-x64-5.9.3.run, when I run it, get:

```
# ./qt-opensource-linux-x64-5.6.3.run
 Segmentation fault (core dumped)
```

I tried many times, same. I also tried to run qt-opensource-linux-x64-5.6.3.run, same.

I have the same virtualbox in another Windows host, everything is fine.

Can anyone give me some clues? Thanks!

Comment: Random segfaults are often caused by failing RAM; try a [memtest](https://www.memtest86.com/).

Comment: Please install Qt from repository, not from developer. It is well packaged. If you plan to distribute your application it would be better if you use Qt version from current LTS release. Your users will be happy until 2021 in case of 16.04 LTS.

Answer (score 1):

You can sometimes get a segmentation fault when trying to install software that was manually downloaded from the buggy interspiderweb. Failing RAM can also cause segmentation faults as fkraiem mentioned in a comment, but I don't think that this is what's happening here because if a RAM stick was failing it would cause problems in the Windows host too.

Qt5 comes with its own Integrated Development Environment (IDE), named Qt Creator, so installing qt-opensource-linux-x64-5.6.3.run is not necessary. The easy way to install Qt5 is to install qtcreator from the default Ubuntu repositories. Open the terminal and type:

```
sudo apt install qtcreator # installs Qt 5.5.1 in 16.04
```

If getting the latest version of Qt5 is critical, you can get Qt Creator based on Qt 5.9.1 in Ubuntu 17.10 or wait for Ubuntu 18.04 to be released and get Qt Creator based on Qt 5.9.3.